# Mobile Horizontal Scroll Not Left & Right

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am having an issue with an element that I want to have horizontal scrolling capabilities. It works on desktop, but touch gestures are not working properly.

Mobile Viewing- The scroll appears, but the gestures are for vertical scrolling.

1. Touch+Drag Up = Scroll Right
2. Touch+Drag Down = Scroll Left

Here's my code.

```
<https://codepen.io/trupert77/pen/QWazBKY>
```

Here's a preview link that will be live for the next 2 days.

1. https://lcxm3t55b0vqevvv-6871711805.shopifypreview.com
2. When that preview link is clicked. Input the URL> https://carletonequipment.com/pages/bobcat

Apologies if this isn't formatted properly. I'm a bit new.